# flutter share state across multiple instances of a widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-state

In my flutter app, I have a `ConnectivityStatus` widget which displays the current connection status of the app to my raspberry pi. In the `initState` of my widget, I subscribe to a timer to check the connection every 5 seconds and update the state accordingly, then unsubscribe upon disposal.

The issue is, when multiple screens use the `ConnectivityStatus` widget, such as in a stack navigator setup, I now have two concurrent subscriptions as neither instance has disposed. This causes many redundant, unneeded requests to occur.

What I really want is to either share a single instance of the widget across multiple screens, or have one global state multiple instances can access.

How can I achieve this or what are other recommended solutions to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way of achieving this would be to use InheritedWidget to pass the ConnectivityStatus to the descending widgets.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html

You could also look into other state management solutions such as Provider
https://pub.dev/packages/provider
or Bloc
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using Provider and creating a `RPIService` that sends a stream of connectivity status.

```
class RPIService {
  var RPIstatus = ValueNotifier<Status>(Status('offline'));

RPIService(){

rpi...listen((cstatus){
RPIstatus.add(Status(cstatus));

});

}}

class Status {
final String statusMessage;
 Status(this.statusMessage);
}
```

main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [

       Provider<UserService>(
       create: (context) => UserService(),
       lazy: false,

       ),
        StreamProvider<Status>(
          create: (context) =>
              Provider.of<RPIService>(context, listen: false).RPIstatus,
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Your app',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: YourHome(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

yourHome.dart

```
class YourHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Status>(builder: (context, status, _) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Text(status.status),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is to use `GlobalKey`, since is the official Flutter way to share a single widget state across the app.

In a `key.dart` file:

```dart
final GlobalKey<ConnectivityStatusState> connectivityStatusKey = GlobalKey();
```

When you create your `ConnectivityStatus` widget:

```dart
ConnectivityStatus(
  key: connectivityStatusKey,
  ...
)
```

Where you want to access the `ConnectivityStatus` state:

```dart
connectivityStatusKey.currentState.anythingPublicInThisState()
```

To use this, make sure your state class is public (without a `_`) and the `ConnectivityStatus` widget is present **and unique** in the widget tree.

Hope this will help!